# Eclipse Debugger - breakpoints in entry of method not hit

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have the following problem in my eclipse Luna 4.1.1

When I put a breakpoints in method entry the debugger do not jump right into the code..

only after pressing step-over(F6) 2 times its jumping inside my method.

Also the line number display in the stack-trace different form  my java source file.

[image]

Comment: Are you running class files compiled by Eclipse from that source file, or is it something you attached as the sources to a jar?

Answer (score 0):

From the image that you shared, 
The stack trace is pointing to the class *UpdateOrderActionAttributesImplAug*
while the source code refers to a different class *UpdateOrderActionAttributesImpl*